# invoke formula in excel via epplus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

I have an excel sheet in ASP.NET MVC4 C# project and I am able to read from excel sheet successfully using EPPlus. Now, I want to be able to pass in 2 numbers into cell C:2 and C:3 and be able to invoke formula in C:4 which is =SUM(C2:C3).

So from C# I want to pass in 4 and 6 and invoke the formula and be able to get the result back from C:4 which is 40 (SUM of 10 and 30). How do I accomplish that in C#.

In the following code, I get back zero for d.Average

```
d.Average = Convert.ToDouble(currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value);
```

Here is my following code in c# so far to traverse a row.

```
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
            var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
            currentWorksheet.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
            currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula = "=SUM(C2:C3)";
            currentWorksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 10;
            currentWorksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 30;
            package.Save();


        }

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
            var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
            d.Average = Convert.ToDouble(currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: What is d.FinalResult? What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 26):

Skip the `=` in the formula string.

Replace `currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula = "=SUM(C2:C3)";`

with

`currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula = "SUM(C2:C3)";`

Answer (score 10):

As of EpPlus 4.0.1.1, there is an extension method `Calculate(this ExcelRangeBase range)`. Invoke it before accessing `Value` property:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Calculate();
```

and `currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value` will return the expected value of `40` after that.

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing my previous answer and found out that the calculation engine of EPPLUS is still in development.

See [this discussion](http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/241913) on CodePlex. (dating from 2011)

A cite from the roadmap page:

> Version 3.2
>
> **Formula parser, calc engine**
>
> Replacing the Package API with DotNetZip
>
> New cellstore to imporve insert, delete performance and memory consumtion
>
> Last edited Feb 14, 2013