# C# EPPlus not evaluating formula SUM(A3:B3)

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have just started working with EPPlus. i have data table which has some numeric data and formula. when i load data table by EPPlus and save to excel then formula not evaluated i found when i open the same excel file. formula lies in excel cell as string like **SUM(A3:B3)**

To evaluate formulate i have tried many options of EPPLUS and those are listed here

```
pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Calculate();
pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Cells["A3"].Calculate();
pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Cells["B3"].Calculate();
ws.Calculate();
```

Here i am referring my full sample code where formula not working. please have a look and tell me what i need to add in my code to evaluate formula.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
    string path = @"d:\EPPLUS_DT_Excel.xlsx";
    Stream stream = File.Create(path);

    using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, false);
        //pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Calculate();
        //pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Cells["A3"].Calculate();
        //pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Test"].Cells["B3"].Calculate();
        ws.Calculate();
        pack.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}

public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    string strSum = "", strColName, strImmediateOneUp = "", strImmediateTwoUp = "";

    int startsum = 0;
    int currow = 0;
    bool firstTimeSum = true;

    int NumRows = 3;
    int NumColumns = 2;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    for (int col = 0; col < NumColumns; col++)
    {
        strColName = GenerateColumnText(col);
        DataColumn datacol = new DataColumn(strColName, typeof(object));
        dt.Columns.Add(datacol);
    }


    for (int row = 0; row < NumRows; row++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();

        for (int col = 0; col < NumColumns; col++)
        {
            if (row < 2)
            {
                dt.Rows[row][col] = Convert.ToInt32(new Random().Next(1, NumRows));
            }
            else
            {
                if (firstTimeSum)
                {
                    if (row - currow == 2)
                    {
                        currow = row;
                        startsum = 0;
                        firstTimeSum = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startsum = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (row - currow == 3)
                    {
                        currow = row;
                        startsum = 0;
                    }
                }


                if (startsum == 0)
                {
                    strColName = GenerateColumnText(col);
                    strImmediateOneUp = strColName + ((row + 1) - 1).ToString();
                    strImmediateTwoUp = strColName + ((row + 1) - 2).ToString();
                    strSum = string.Format("+SUM({0}:{1})", strImmediateTwoUp, strImmediateOneUp);
                    dt.Rows[row][col] = strSum;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows[row][col] = Convert.ToInt32(new Random().Next(1, NumRows));
                }
            }

        }

        startsum = 1;
    }
    return dt;
}

private string GenerateColumnText(int num)
{
    string str = "";
    char achar;
    int mod;
    while (true)
    {
        mod = (num % 26) + 65;
        num = (int)(num / 26);
        achar = (char)mod;
        str = achar + str;
        if (num > 0) num--;
        else if (num == 0) break;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: if you see "SUM(A3:B3)" in a cell you are either missing the "=" sign or the cell is formatted as Text.  Check your cell formatting.

Comment: it is formula convention for EPPlus that we should not provide = sign. that is the reason i remove = sign from sum. see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138440/10839668

Comment: The basic how-to page [is here](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation).  So don't use "+SUM()", just "SUM".

Answer (score 2):

When adding a formula to a cell you use the `Formula` property. When you load a range from a `DataTable` using `LoadFromDataTable` it has no way of knowing that some of the values are meant to be interpreted as formulas.

You can use `LoadDataTable` to populate the cells on which the formulas will operate, but for the formulas you'll need to set the `Formula` property.